# Does the application controller have an associated template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I run

> rails new proj1

I can do

> rails generate controller abc def

and that creates among other things,   .\app\views\abc\def.html.erb

And I can edit config.rb to say

`get '/', to: 'abc#def'`
or
`root 'abc#def'`

And that will load that `def.html.erb` template when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

But I'm interested if I can do that without creating that new controller.  I'm interested in whether I can go to the template just using the application controller.

So, for example,  I can edit `.\app\controllers\application_controller.rb` and add

```
def a 
end
```

then does the application controller behave like other controllers and try to render a corresponding .html.erb file e.g. the 'a' action would try to render a.html.erb? If so, I can't find where I should place the a.html.erb file?

Other controllers have a subdirectory for them within views, and files within that subdirectory for each action, and one can do them manually or by using e.g. `rails generate controller blah a b c`  to generate the controller with actions and with a template for each action.

But I can't see that for the application controller.. I can't see where its views are.

Comment: ApplicationController generally does not contain methods which respond to the router. It can if you want it to, but it's not a very common thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

#### routes.rb:

```
get '/', to: "application#root"
```

#### application_controller.rb

```
def root
end
```

#### app/views/application/root.html.erb

```
hello world
```

Running the server and visiting `localhost:3000` prints "hello world"

Sinatra does things similar to this. Routes and controller actions are basically combined and it'd be up to you to implement rails-like controllers yourself if you wanted them.